# GWT Dev Mode For IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, gwt-dev-mode

I see that the GWT Development Mode plugin is available for Internet Explorer 8, but the browser crashes when I start it.  The stack trace says there's an error in oophm.dll.  I'm running it on a VirtualBox instance with Windows 7.  Are there any special steps for setting up dev mode in IE8?

Comment: It might be helpful if you can provide the entire stack trace in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Dev mode doesn’t seem to play well with Windows 7.  Try downloading a windows XP vm from:
http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools

You’ll also need to manually install the dev mode for IE 8 plug in from the following location because the built-in link for IE 8 is broken:
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.0/plugins/ie/prebuilt/

Comment: I used to run devMode on IE8/Win7 successfully. Very slow, but working.

Comment: Alexp, when did you have dev mode working with IE8/Win7?  Was it in the last year?

Comment: I had HP Envy 15 notebook with Win 7 installed. IE8 was originally installed there too and never updated for the purpose of testing the application on that browser. Last time I used that config was about two months ago. I was using dev mode on GWT since 1.7.x till 2.5

Comment: This is only working for select entry points into my app.  Most entry points are still causing this crash.

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying superdevmode?

- http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html
- [Super Dev mode in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330001/super-dev-mode-in-gwt) (stackoverflow)

Disclaimer: I don't know if it works on IE 8 -- but I think it was designed to work on any modern broser. One main reason for creating it was to get rid of the need of maintaining various browser plugins...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I really need to be able to pause the debugger inside of the Java code.  I was under the impression that you can't do that with Super Dev Mode.

Comment: I thought this would work in the browser debugger via source maps, but I am not sure whether IE supports source maps (at all or starting with a specific version)... http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Comment: IE doesn't support source maps :(