# Super dev mode + JSP page in Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I have a .jsp page (the main page of my gwt module) and I'm trying to enable super dev mode as I'm migrating to gwt 2.6.
Following the explanations I found out on internet, once I launch the codeserver and add the bookmarklets, next I gotta open the page in my browser, so I call the jsp page from my tomcat server.
The problem is that nothing happens, and looking at the chrome console it seems it is unable to find my **module/module.nocache.js**
Any idea?

**EDIT : added .gwt.xml**

```
<inherits name="XXX.frontend.gwt.Framework"/>

<inherits name="XXX.frontend.gwt.sample.frontend.module.blanc.Module"/>

<!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
<source path='client'/>
<source path='shared'/>

<!-- Specify the application entry point class                  -->
<entry-point class='XXX.frontend.gwt.client.FrameworkEntryPoint'/>


<!-- Compile for specific browser -->
<!-- <set-property name="user.agent" value="ie8,ie9,ie10,gecko1_8,safari" /-->

<!-- Compile for specific language -->
<extend-property name="locale" values="fr" />
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="fr" />
<set-configuration-property name='xsiframe.failIfScriptTag' value='FALSE' />
<set-configuration-property name="devModeUrlWhitelistRegexp" value="http://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)(:\d+)?/.*" />
<add-linker name="xsiframe" />
<set-property name="compiler.useSourceMaps" value="true" />
```

Comment: Maybe this helps.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330001/super-dev-mode-in-gwt/18333050#18333050

Comment: Already read that but it doesn't help, since my problem happens when opening my webapp, I suppose there is a way to wire both servers but I still can't figure it out :/

Answer (score 1):

You have to load your `.nocache.js` file from your codeserver instance.

In your `.jsp` you must have something like this:

```
<script src="http://localhost:9876/myapp/myapp.nocache.js"></script>
```

In your gwt.xml you need these lines as well:

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
<set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true"/>

<set-property name="compiler.useSourceMaps" value="true" />
```

Comment: Hi, sorry manolo for answering this late, but i had some problems with the rc and waited for the final release. I did what you told me, but I get this error saying : **xsrf: ERROR: The module path requested, /myapp/, is not in the same web application as this servlet** haven't you faced anything of this sort? thanks in advance

Comment: May be you have to set: devModeUrlWhitelistRegexp in your module descirptor. That was something I missed.

Comment: @ElHoss that doesn't change anything!

Comment: It looks like you have some problems with your SOP. Are you using a proxy or a redirect? It looks like you are using different domains. Can you post the domains you are working with?

Comment: well I have a tomcat containing my server code, and the codeserver, tomcat at 8888 and codeserver at 9876. but if my jsp is at 8888 it will call the nocache at 9876 which is going to do later some rpc calls at another domain, and that's not allowed ...

Comment: Ar you using the same hostname? Could you post your .gwt.xml?

Comment: hostname is localhost as i said, on one port tomcat at 8888 and codeserver at 9876