# How to speed up the gwt 2.6 Super Dev Mode compiler?

Tags: gwt, compiler-construction, gwt2

I'm upgrading my GWT project to 2.6 Release Candidate 1 (GWT 2.6 RC1), and trying the new **[Super Dev Mode](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html)**.

I use for the normal dev mode:
in my `gwt.xml` :

```
 <!-- i compile just for Chrome -->
 <set-property name="user.agent" value="safari"/>

 <!-- with one languge -->
 <extend-property name="locale" values="en_UK" ></extend-property>
```

Unfortunately, i waste 3min of my life each compile which can be around 3 hours/day :s, my hair start shedding bcs of that!

Does all old normal compiler optimizations still same in the new Super dev mode, or there some new ones for the new compiler that can make it faster?

I'll appreciate all ideas and suggestions.

i'm using : hibernate 4, spring DAO, GWT 2.6, 50 tables and more than 100 views

Comment: Are you sure you use the super dev mode at all? You have to compile the application once, after this you have to hit the recompile button. http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330001/super-dev-mode-in-gwt

Comment: Yes, is that out of normal? with a project in that size and technologies(edits)