# GWT Super Dev Mode - bindAddress - changes not showing

Tags: gwt

I have used GWT Super Dev Mode since 2.5 without any problems. Recently I upgraded Eclipse and GWT to 2.6 at the same time. Everything seems to work up to the point I make any changes to my code:

1. Start web server - ok
2. Start super dev mode codeserver - initial compile ok
3. Open code server - ok
4. Open page - ok
5. Make code change
6. Hit bookmark "Dev mode on" - compile ok
7. Reload page - no changes!?

I use "-bindAddress 192.168.5.151" in my run configs to be able to browse from different devices. If I remove -bindAddress everything works again. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In GWT 2.6, to make SuperDevMode more secure (and, BTW, it's now enabled by default, so no need to set the `devModeRedirectEnabled` property any longer), it's now only enabled on `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` by default.

If you open your browser console you should see a line saying something like:

> `Ignoring non-whitelisted Dev Mode URL: http://192.168.5.151:9876/`

You can whitelist more codeserver URLs using a regexp in the `devModeUrlWhitelistRegexp` configuration property. FYI, the default configuration would read something like this:

```xml
<set-configuration-property name="devModeUrlWhitelistRegexp" value="http://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)(:\d+)?/.*" />
```

In your case, you'd use:

```xml
<set-configuration-property name="devModeUrlWhitelistRegexp" value="http://(mymachinename|192\.168\.5\.151)(:\d+)?/.*" />
```

BTW, this was explicitly called out in the release notes: http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_6_0

Comment: Thomas, thanks for your answer. I added the devModeUrlWhitelistRegexp propterty to all my *.gwt.xml files and restarted but still no changes.

Comment: @Carl you should check the edit. There was an error in the regex.

Comment: See 2.6.0 (RC1) release notes (Developer Tools chapter) http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_6_0_RC1

Comment: @Thomas Thank you!