# Can not reflect changes using gwt-maven-plugin superdev

Tags: gwt, gwt-maven-plugin, gwt-super-dev-mode

Follow steps [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330001/super-dev-mode-in-gwt),
I use `gwt-maven-plugin 2.6.0`, when I run `mvn gwt:run-codeserver` it compiled successfully:

```
[INFO] binding: user.agent=safari
[INFO] Compiling module com.example.myModule
[INFO]    Validating units:
[INFO]       Ignored 3 units with compilation errors in first pass.
[INFO] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
[INFO]    ...
[INFO]    Compiling 1 permutation
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 0...
[INFO]       Source Maps Enabled
[INFO]    Compile of permutations succeeded
[INFO] Linking into C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\gwt-codeserver-5664784549647002986.tmp\com.example.myModule\compile-4\war\myModule;
 Writing extras to C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\gwt-codeserver-5664784549647002986.tmp\com.example.myModule\compile-4\extras\myModule
[INFO]    Link succeeded
[INFO]    Compilation succeeded -- 3.401s
[INFO] Compile completed in 3496 ms
```

Then I started the dev server using `mvn install gwt:run`, made changes on my source file and click the `Dev Mode On` bookmark. After compiling the changes cannot reflect to UI: the UI always show old values.

Any ideas on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in gwt-maven-plugin up to (including) 2.6.0; you have to run `mvn process-classes gwt:run-codeserver` instead of just `mvn gwt:run-codeserver`. This is fixed in 2.6.1.

Also, if you change anything in `src/main/resources`, you'll have to run `mvn process-resources` to make your changes available to Super Dev Mode (this is because you might use resource filtering, so Super Dev Mode doesn't directly look at `src/main/resources`).

Similarly, if you use plugins that generate resources or Java sources, you'll have to run them manually (e.g. `mvn generate-sources` or `mvn generate-resources`; or just use the same `mvn process-resources` as above, which will do everything at once). This will be necessary for example if you use `gwt:generateAsync` and change your GWT-RPC interface (note that you'll also have to redeploy your server-side code).

---

Note: I just updated my answer in the linked post for GWT 2.6.0, and added a note about GWT-RPC, and the gwt-maven-plugin bug.

Comment: gwt-maven-plugin 2.6.1 seems to correct this problem ( http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/whats_new.html )