# GWT Super Dev Mode RPC 404

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt-super-dev-mode

I am trying to get started with super dev mode. I have super dev mode running, and have a web server serving up my main html page, where I am able to do 'Dev mode on' and recompile the module. Now I am trying to get this page to access my RequestFactory and RPC servlets. I started up regular dev mode and have the servlets available at localhost:8888/gwtRequest. So now I have three servers running:

```
http://localhost:9876/ - GWT Code Server
http://localhost:8080/ - Mongoose web server serving /war directory
http://localhost:8888/ - GWT Dev Mode running servlets
```

How do I point my app to the correct servlet container? And are all those servers necessary? I get a 404 right now because it is looking at `http://localhost:8080/gwtRequest`.

Here's a snippet of web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>requestFactoryServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.example.server.util.ExampleRequestFactoryServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>requestFactoryServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/gwtRequest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Past that, are there any ways I can make this less convoluted? Maybe some new feature takes care of some of these headaches? I'm hoping to setup other developers with the environment once I know how! And hopefully not make it too much more difficult to push to production (i.e. hopefully minimal configuration/code changes).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need 2 servers:

- one that serves your static files and server-side code (servlets). This includes a version of your app compiled to JavaScript (you don't need to update it often though!). This can be the server that's embedded in DevMode, but can also be a standalone Jetty or Tomcat or whatever, or things like the tomcat7-maven-plugin or jetty-maven-plugin in Maven or the jetty plugin in Gradle.
- the SuperDevMode's CodeServer

Note that if you use GWT-RPC, you'll want to launch your server with the `gwt.codeserver.port` system property set to the port of the CodeServer (assuming they live on the same machine). That way, when your browser (which runs a more recent client-side code than what you compiled to JS and deployed to your server) talks to your servlet, that one will load the GWT-RPC serialization policy from the CodeServer. Otherwise, GWT-RPC is likely to fail with an `IncompatibleRemoteServiceException`.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333050/116472