# Does GWT 2.6 Super Dev Mode supports hot swap (recompile) and how?

Tags: java, gwt, hotswap, gwt-super-dev-mode, gwt-dev-mode

Recently I started to use Super Dev Mode to get look&feel of it. It took me couple of hours to get it up but I didn't find out how and actually can you use SDM for faster development using hot swapping. 
Using Dev Mode all I had to do is save my changes in IDE and refresh the browser page. Now my code changes needs to get transferred to the code server to be recompiled? Am I right or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is click the `DevMode On` bookmarklet and `Compile` button. This is for client-side code only though.

For server-side code, whereas DevMode can serve your webapp and you can reload it with a single click to get your changes in, CodeServer only deals with the client side, so you have to deploy your webapp to a server (that said, you can use DevMode if you want). You then need to re-deploy your webapp when you make changes to your server-side code.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333050/116472 for a detailed step-by-step howto.

Comment: So I just click DevMode&Compile once more, despite the fact I'm still in DevMode and debugging?

Comment: Yes, `DevMode On` just displays the dialog, whether you're already in "dev mode" or not, then click `Compile` to recompile your app taking into account the changes you made to the source files (note: `COmpile` is actually also a bookmarklet that you can add to your bookmarks so save you one click)

Comment: @Tomas:Here i have one question ,i have multiple maven based application,If i made any changes to the code then i need to compile the application,deploy and need to launch in SDM?Is it correct?

Comment: @mohammedsameen No. And the link above is for GWT 2.6; things have changed (for the better) in 2.7.