# Run GWT application in super dev mode

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I'm trying to run GWT application in super dev mode with maven via mvn gwt:run-codeserver. This plugin gave me to a localhost page `http://localhost:9876/`, I bookmarked the `Dev mode On` as suggestion and then access the link provided in the page.

Then I clicked `Dev Mode On` on bookmark bar, however I got messages
`Can't find any GWT Modules on this page.`

So how can I run the application in super dev mode, do I have to deploy the app in a web server like Tomcat, JBoss ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you do need to deploy your application first.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333050/116472 for a step-by-step guide.

GWT 2.7 will introduce a way to launch your webapp in an embedded Jetty server (the same as in DevMode) while using SuperDevMode, and without even requiring the bookmarklets. See http://www.sencha.com/blog/getting-started-with-gwt-super-dev-mode/ (note that this is already available in the 2.7.0-SNAPSHOT that are deployed nightly)