# How to debug gwt application without using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, gwt, jboss

I have a project which consists of multiple wars deployed on jboss. These wars are generated by running build.xml from eclipse and then copying to deploy folder on jboss. All these projects are Java projects and thus I can't debug them by adding server on eclipse. Something like below.

Eclipse -> Multiple Java projects (Java + GWT) -> Produce WAR (run build.xml) -> Copy to jboss/../..deploy -> start.bat

How to debug this code and know which java class/function is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

As GWT translates the client side code to JavaScript you cannot debug it like a normal Java Webapplication via a debug port.

You need to either use DevMode or [SuperDevMode](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html). DevMode has the advantage of letting you debug directly in the IDE like any other Java application. The disadvantage is that you need an old browser for that (Firefox <= 24 i think). SuperDevMode uses source maps and you debug the application in your browser but you need to make the changes in the IDE so its a bit less comfortable in my opinion. SuperDevMode is recomended though because support for DevMode is not given anymore.

Comment: But SuperDevMode works for Eclipse. In my case, eclipse can't link runtime with code as it's only used for editing and building code. Eclipse doesn't know about wars and deployment.

Comment: Well DevMode is linked to your IDE while SuperDevMode is not. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25566279/run-gwt-application-in-super-dev-mode you need to deploy that application as SuperDevMode application and link it to the code somewhere to see the source maps. From that you debug in your Browser not in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

There's the excellent maven gwt plugin to use the super dev mode (SDM) of GWT, but you should be able to startup the SDM from ant as well.

The debugger is then the debugger of your browser, I recommend the chrome debugger, as it's sourcemap support is excellent.

Your way to work would then be:

- build the application as described, compile with the SDM enabled in your gwt.xml. Usually, all that is required is using the xsi-frame linker.
- deploy your application.
- Run the superdevmode code server on the sources used to build your code.
- start your application, navigate to codeserver and drag the `dev mode on` link to your browsers toolbar.
- navigate to your app and click on the devmode on link. The codeserver will now take over and let you compile the code.

Now use the builtin browser debugger to debug your code, set breakpoints and inspect variables. It requires to get used to it a bit, but it works very nice.

Change code as required and just let the SDM compile your application again. No need to rebundle. The SDM client will inject the fresh compile directly into the browser. If I didn't forget something, you will be able to debug your application with java source-stepping without eclipse.

See a description here http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html