# Super Dev Mode GWT 2.6 with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I am really stuck with this!

A year ago I was using the classical Dev Mode.
Now I need to update the application and I cannot figure out how to change the Run configuration.

I usually run into solutions like this:
[Super Dev mode in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330001/super-dev-mode-in-gwt)
but it is not working

Is there a recent tutorial that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to setup the Super Dev mode, but there is a way to use the Dev Mode on ChromiumPortable:

> ---- By Alex Epshteyn ---
>
> The hack I came up with (for Windows) was to install "portable"
>   versions of Chromium and Firefox.
>
> Portable Firefox 24:
>   http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox-portable-esr Portable
>   Chromium 35: http://crportable.sourceforge.net/
>
> Then you need to manually install the GWT plugin into Chromium, since
>   it's now disabled on the Chrome Web Store:
>   1. download the file GWT-Developer-Plugin_v1.0.11357.crx from http://chrome-extension-downloader.com/ (entering ID number
>   jpjpnpmbddbjkfaccnmhnkdgjideieim into the search field)
>   2. drag and drop the downloaded file into the chrome://extensions/ tab to install the plugin

---

details here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/QSEjbhhHB4g