# Is it possible to debug GWT anymore?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

Is it just me, or is it even possible to run/debug a GWT application anymore?

A brand new install of the Google Plugin for Eclipse (Juno), create a new Web Application with GWT + GAE, run/debug. FAIL.

This is on a Mac, with Chrome, Firefox and Safari. The browser plugin is incompatible with Safari and Firefox, says it's compatible with Chrome but always asks to reinstall it.

Any ideas/tips?

-Shane

**Update**: Ok, so I went back to Firefox ESR 24 (https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/) and this worked. This will hold me over until GWT 2.7 releases.

Comment: always had the same problem with Chrome. don't remember, but i think refreshing the page worked for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Browsers (all but IE) have removed the features needed for the GWT Dev Plugin. The way forward is "Super Dev Mode", which doesn't require a browser plugin, but also no longer uses the Java debugger (code is compiled to JavaScript "as fast as possible", and debugged using Source Maps in the browser's dev tools).

SuperDevMode is unfortunately not that simple to get started with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333050/116472

That being said, GWT 2.7 will soon be released and DevMode behavior changes to actually use SuperDevMode (and you can turn back to "classic" DevMode by passing `-nosuperDevMode`); so things will "magically" start to work again just by updating your GWT SDK.

Note: SuperDevMode also has the huge advantage compared to "classic" DevMode that it works in any browser, even mobile browsers!

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the heads-up on GWT 2.7. Unfortunately, after reading up on it a bit, there doesn't appear to be a release date any time soon, so for now the only solution that I can use today is by using the Firefox ESR 24 build.

Comment: SuperDevMode exists since GWT 2.5, the initial setup is not really user-friendly, but no much less than installing an old version of Firefox and making sure it doesn't polute your current profile. There are snapshots of GWT 2.7 built nightly if you want to try them (only available for build tools using managed dependencies though: Maven, gradle, etc.); and GWT 2.7 beta1 is about to be released (we have a Steering Committee meeting later today to sort out some blocking issues, such as whether we require Java 7 or not).

Comment: Thanks for the update on GWT 2.7, Thomas. I'll wait until the beta's out so I don't have to go through the 2.5 setup procedure.