# Eclipse can't find com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode when creating debug configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I have old project written in GWT and I need to use eclipse to run it. I've installed eclipse mars and gwt plugin from [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.5), imported the project, but when I create debug configuration (web application) I got empty Main class in first tab, I've try to search for the class but when I type gwt or dev I get empty list.

Did I miss something? Why eclipse can't find class `com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode`?

Comment: A couple of things to check: 1) Is it marked as "Use GWT" in Properties->Google->Web Toolkit. 2) are there any GWT SDKs installed in Window->Preferences->Google->Web Toolkit?

Comment: @Stik Properties show GWT 2.6.1 (selected specific version) that I need to use and window show GWT 2.7.0, I've installed both gwt plugin and sdk from google url.

Comment: Just so you don't spend too much time on this DevMode problem if you don't need it: [Super Dev Mode](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html). DevMode doesn't work anymore with newer version of browsers because they won't allow the plugin that was used to be installed. See also [Is it possible to debug GWT anymore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354622/is-it-possible-to-debug-gwt-anymore)

Comment: @JonSampson I'm using old version of Chromium for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue by copy pasting `com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode` into main class name.