# GWT plugin issue in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gwt

I have been trying to run GWT program in chrome. When I paste the URL in address bar then its says "Development Mode requires the GWT Developer Plugin" so I have installed it in my PC and in the chrome extension section also shows this plugin added into chrome.

Check this image :

[image]

After restart the browser when I again paste the URL and tried to run it browser, browser shows again "Development Mode requires the GWT Developer Plugin".

That means browser needs again to install it but I have already completed this process.

Help me about this issue.

I used Windows - 7 with chrome - 46.

Comment: For the poor ones like me, meandering through posts wondering how to run `super dev mode` which is the solution to this if you're on the latest GWT/Eclipse. You right-click the project in eclipse,  `Run As -> Web Application (GWT Super Dev Mode)` and it works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

From that page:

> Note: the plugin no longer works on Linux because Chrome is dropping NPAPI support. It will also stop working on Windows 7 and Mac sometime in 2014. See http://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation

So it's no wonder that it doesn't work; quite expected actually.

The real question is: why are you still using "legacy" dev mode rather than "super dev mode"? super dev mode is the default behavior in GWT 2.7, so I suppose you're using an ancient version of GWT ⇒ **update to the latest when it's out** (2.8-beta-1 is currently in smoke test, with 2.8 expected by the end of the year)

Comment: I am using GWT 2.6. How can I use super dev mode in GWT 2.6?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333050/116472; but it's much easier to update to GWT 2.7 (and the overall dev experience much faster too).

Answer (score 2):

From GWT Website ,http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_6_1

GWT Development Mode will no longer be available for Chrome sometime in 2014, so we improved alternate ways of debugging. There are improvements to Super Dev Mode, asserts, console logging, and error messages.
This is because of newer chrome version.Use Super Dev Mode

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use the plugin, it still works in IE11.

Else I would recommend to move to [Super Dev Mode](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html).