# Jrebel with GWT: not detecting changes in client side in superdevmode

Tags: gwt, jrebel

I am using jrebel in my GWT project .

When i run my Application in classic mode , Jrebel detect changes in my client side and every thing works fine.

But when i run in superdev mode , Jrebel Does Not detect any changes in my client side .(Server side is fine).

Secondly If i run in classic mode with Jrebel  , it always gives memory leak after some time

I did increas the permsize but no luck

http://screencast.com/t/vWwU018yTq

Any idea what could be the reason .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`JRebel` have nothing to do with `gwt`'s `SDM`.
When you use `SDM` you have to use bookmark to trigger compilation of `java` -> `js` code.

Comment: Bookmark? It's been more than a year that this is deprecated!

Comment: @ThomasBroyer that sounds great!

Comment: what should i do to make jrebel working with my GWT code please. Also if i run my GWT application on tomcat (It gives the message in tomcat console that jrebel will be detecting code etc..), But its not working there as well, Actually at run time from my ui, I have the option where user can upload a widget in our app,which i need to load with the help of jrebel, please guide

Comment: @junaidp take a look at instructions about SDM from Thomas Broyer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333050/755183